# Print Plot in Octave in Background

Tags: gnuplot, octave

Currently, I use `print -dpng foo.png` to print a plot to file in Octave 3.0.1 on Ubuntu.

Sometimes, I generate thousands of images in a loop.

Whenever a new image pops up, it grabs the mouse control precluding me from multitasking.

Is there anyway to print silently or quietly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would be easier to answer your question with a little more information about what you are doing. But with a little guessing maybe this is what you need:

```
f = figure
set(f, "visible", "off")
plot([1,2,3,4])
print("MyPNG.png", "-dpng")
```

Comment: You can do `f=figure('Visible','off');` so that the figure's initial state is not visible.

Comment: I tried that, but once the print statement was executed the figure popped up again. After some experimentation I got ASCII to print without any pop-up GUI's, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55347194/1147688).