# How can I run an octave command from the command line, and be able to have a window pop up?

Tags: command-line, octave

I would like to use octave's plot command from the windows command line, without having to actually open octave's interface, but a window with the plot must still be opened. Doing it in one line would be preferable, since it is a command that is being passed to the command line from python. how can I do this?

I have found out that typing

```
C:\Users\username\Octave\Octave-5.1.0.0>octave -W
```

makes it so no window pops up, but I don't know how to get any commands to actually run, and the description for `-W` in the octave documentation seems to say that it disables graphics, as well as the startup window.

Comment: I think , it has answer here . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843014/getting-octave-to-plot-when-invoking-a-function-from-the-command-line

Comment: @user1319128 Thank you. the answer I needed was there