# Matlab/Octave export 2D-plot as image without showing it

Tags: matlab, octave

I need to create an ocatve script which will generate a 2D-plot and then directly export it as image without actually plotting it.

Hypothetical Example:

```
x=1:10;
exportDirectly(x,'myImage.jpg');
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6289807/572616) question can help.

Comment: This answer has a few related techniques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721255/axis-coordinates-to-pixel-coordinates-matlab/7721402#7721402

Comment: I found it: octave:2> f=figure("visible","off");
octave:3> plot([10,1,20,5,24]);
octave:4> print("MyPNG.png", "-dpng"); The credit goes to Woltan for pointing out a useful answer! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a figure, but turn of visibility. Then plot and save as usual.

something like

```
fh = figure()
fh.set('Visible','Off')
%Some Plotting here
print(fh)
```

That might be of some help...