# Octave -- Plotting from Terminal Command Line

Tags: plot, command-line-interface, octave

Background:

I'm new to Octave, as of today.
I am running GNU Octave, version 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I'm using the command-line interface at the terminal (ie, open the terminal and, type "octave").
I'm aware that there is a GUI, but I want to see if I can get this working in the terminal [such a setup is my preference in most applications]

PROBLEM:

Plots are plotted in text.  As in:

[image: TextBasedPlot]

How can I get a good-looking plot in a plotting window?  I genuinely haven't been able to find this information in 10 minutes of Googling...I think it should be easier than that....maybe someday this post will be the easy solution for others.

Best,
-Ryan

Comment: You could show your code please

Comment: Umm.. I may have solved my own issue.  I was trying to fix something else, so I followed the instructions here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292721/error-running-octave-in-ubuntu-16-04

cd .config/octave; 

sudo chown user qt-settings


And it seems to be working now......I'll post as an answer if the problem doesn't come back.

Comment: I had the exact opposite problem of always getting the GUI figure (even if executed from CLI) and not being able to get the ASCII plots you show above, but some investigation [solved my problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55347194/1147688).

Answer (score 1):

I personally do this a lot; it looks like you have it installed in a *nix environment... Octave can produce nice looking figures through cooperation with a couple graphic toolkits, GNUPlot being the one i'm more familiar with.

Check out the documentation at: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Plotting.html

Without seeing your code we're kind of just guessing. I would try something like

```
figure();
```

to see if you get a fresh plot window, or try

```
available_graphics_toolkits()
```

to ensure that you actually have something installed to generate separate figures.

Comment: I'm far more impressed at the ASCII plots to be honest. I had no idea! xD